# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, cluster

soy novato en Python y estoy tratando de realizar el algoritmo que hace kmeans con bucles for y sin utilizar "from sklearn.cluster import KMeans" pero al tratar de calcular la distancia entre los puntos aleatorios que genere con los centroides me da un typeError

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
%matplotlib inline

x = np.array([
     #50 datos aleatorios 
])
K = 5
centroides = [
    #5 centroides aleatorios
]
lx = len(x)
lc = len(centroides)
for i in range(lx):
  for j in range(lc):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(x[i],centroides[j])
```

Comment: no he podido replicar tu problema, pero me sale otro error diferente al que dices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que para calcular la distancia euclidiana usando `np.linalg.norm` tienes que enviar un solo argumento, que es la diferencia entre los dos vectores.

En lugar de:

```
np.linalg.norm(x[i], centroides[j])
```

deberías usar:

```
np.linalg.norm(x[i] - centroides[j])
```

## Extra

Por cierto, puedes simplificar la manera en que visitas cada elemento de las listas

```
for valor_x in x:
  for centroide in centroides:
    dist = np.linalg.norm(valor_x-centroide)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y el consejo me fue de mucha ayuda!